# Docbook XML to PDF, no 'ő' and 'ű' characters

Tags: xml, apache-fop, docbook, xslt

I have the following problem for a while. I have been trying to convert Docbook XML to PDF. Almost everything goes well except the PDF file has no 'ő' and 'ű' chars in the text, they are replaced with '#'.

Which programs do I use?
- Cygwin with 'xsltproc'.
- FOP 1.0 (windows)
- Docbook-XSL stylesheet

PS: The docbook files are valid.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Does the font contain those characters?  Do other accented (non-ASCII) characters display correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a font that has those characters. If, for example, you configure Arial.ttf with Apache FOP [1] and customize [2] the DocBook XSL-FO stylesheets to use that font, these characters should work just fine. Please note that the standard base 14 fonts (like Helvetica) available with no FOP configuration do not have these glyphs.

[1] http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/latest/fonts.html#custom

[2] Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:import href="docbook.xsl"/>

  <xsl:param name="fop1.extensions" select="1"/>
  <xsl:param name="body.font.family" select="'Arial'"/>
  <xsl:param name="title.font.family" select="'Arial'"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```